Trying to add sum in one of a column in SSRS table Report



Employee ID
Full Name
Credit Loss
FTE




1
ABC
13.55
1.00


2
XYZ
9.55
0.60


2
XYZ
9.55
0.80


3
DEF
3.44
0.55


4
GHI
6.66
1.00


5
JKL
12.44
0.45


5
JKL
12.44
0.55



Basically, I have these 4 columns, all having different data. There is a scenario where one of the employees could have multiple data, but FTE would still be different. My problem is how do I group FTE column, so data only appear once as adding FTE for employees having more than 1 data. Sorry if that's a silly question.
I tried sum by On FTE column and tried to add Group By parent group but could not figure out anything.
I want the output like this.



Employee ID
Full Name
Credit Loss
FTE




1
ABC
13.55
1.00


2
XYZ
9.55
1.4


3
DEF
3.44
0.55


4
GHI
6.66
1.00


5
JKL
12.44
1.00




SUM seems to be exactly what you need; the SUM of 0.6 and 0.8 is 1.4, and the SUM of 0.45 and 0.55 is 1.00 and those are the values you expect. Demonstrate your attempt(s), explain why they didn't work.

You just need a row group that groups on Employee ID, then the expressions for the other 3 columns would be =MIN(Fields!FullName.Value)' , '=MIN(Fields!CreditLoss.Value) and =SUM(Fields!FTE.Value)

You have a couple of options.
One is to change your query so that you sum the FTE there. Group by whatever you need in the query, and make sure you sum FTE.
The other is to do it in the report itself. You could hide Details if you never need to show how FTE is split. But you’ll need to put the values into the cells that correspond to the group.
I’d change the query, myself.

Basically, one of an example was 0.60000 and 0.4000. I used cast function as float changed to 0.4 and 0.6, used function sum (FTE) it became 4.4 and 6.6 not sure how it became. I did in SQL script

In the end of script, I did group by Employee ID, Name, FTE
